# How to read EMV chip data from the IDTECH spectrum pro device in C#?

Tags: c#, smartcard-reader, emv

I have a requirement to read the EMV supported credit/debit card details from the IDTech Spectrum Pro card reader.

The problem is I should not use the IDTECH EMV related APIS for this. Since the customer have some restriction.

So **is there any APDU command to read the encrypted card data from the CHIP directly using the IDTECH card reader?**

Also

What are the things I need to try/check before starting the implementation since i am new to this?

Hope i will not get downVote!

Comment: Shouldn't you contact IDTech support for this?

Comment: @Martheen,  Sent mail already but response remains NULL. thats why trying here.

Comment: by "I should not " is it that you have the library and you are not supposed to use it due to some reason( say license) or you do not have the library at all ? Do you have the API documentation at least ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No 1:** 
IDTECH Spectrun Pro device come up with their own protocol. So you cant speak with Reader device unless you dontknow the IDTECH Protocol.
So you cant pass the APDU Commands to the reader (in my knowledge)

**No 2:**
So ask your IDTECH support about the reading PAN (EMV tag- 5A) data of the card and Track 2 data (EmV tag - 57) Since normally the reader will return as a Masked/Encrypted data.

**No 3:**
There is one option called "PrePANCtrlData"(0~6) and "PostPANCtrlData"(0~4), So ask them how to set this bit using their dll and ask them Is it possible to get the unmasked data if you set the value to 0 to the same.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Now i understood the flow.